# What is polymorphism,its two forms or multiple forms?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Yesterday, I was asked a question in an interview regarding polymorphism...

> Which of these statements are correct regarding polymorphism?
>
> 1. Polymorphism is a method in which a class can exist in multiple forms.
> 2. Polymorphism is a method in which a class can exist in only Two forms.
> 3. Polymorphism is a method in which diffrent instances of an object displays diffrent behavior
> 4. Polymorphism is a method in which diffrent instances of an object displays same behavior

Comment: The least incorrect statement is #1 :)

Comment: Polymorphism is a method? Instances of an object? Different class *forms*? What the hell?

Comment: I guess in this context the term method relates to methodology, strategy or concept.

Comment: ya frnds i am totally disturbed when asked ?

Comment: Aside from @Tudor's correct clarification, do YOU understand what polymorphism is?  If not, are you asking for better clarification for your own understanding?

Comment: The correct answer is `(5) Thank you, but I think I'll be looking elsewhere for a job.  You obviously don't know what it is and I prefer to work at a place where they do.`

Comment: ya i know that but which is correct and its should me more than one]

Comment: No. Polymorphism is a concept, not a method. Inheritance and interface implementation are two "methods" used to implement polymorphism in Java.  One "class" can't exist in two forms, but more than one class can implement an interface (and more than two for that matter). You can't have different "instances" of an object, but you can have different instances (objects) of a class.  The question betrays the fact that the interviewer DOES NOT GET IT. You DON'T want to work there unless you consider yourself a coding missionary and want to convert them to a correct understanding.

Comment: @PatelMayur If you're still asking which answer is correct, you obviously do not understand polymorphism. You may have a shallow understanding of it, but given all of the terminology of this question, you don't have a solid, deep understanding.

Comment: Or, perhaps, the question was lost in translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of them are correct , here is how : 
Considering few modifications in the question (i hope this was in interviewee's mind)

```
1.Polymorphism is a method in which a class can exist in multiple forms.
```

***Question modified : 
    1'. Polymorphism is a concept (in some languages) by which an instance of a class can exist as a type of many other class types.***

Explanation of why this is true :
   e.g.  C is derived from B , B is derived from A , A is derived from X and X is derived from System.Object (in C#).

Here  instance of class C (  C myc = new C(); ) **myc** can exist as B, A , X , Object.
e.g.   you can pass **myc** to a method which accepts only types of A.

```
2.Polymorphism is a method in which a class can exist in only Two forms.
```

***Modified Question : 
    2'. Polymorphism is a way by which an instance of a class can exist as a type of only 2 other instance types :***

Explanation : Class B is derived from A then B can exists as A or System.Object only i.e. only 2 other forms.

```
3.Polymorphism is a method in which different instances 
 of an object displays different behavior
```

***Modified question :
    3'. Polymorphism is a way in which different instances(of different types) 
    of a class display different behavior***

Explanation : B is derived from A, and A has method called CleanMe() which is not overridden in class B but has same signature and name (C# needs a "new"  keyword for such methods).

Now when you  say

```
A myA = new B();  // instance of B exits as type A
myA.CleanMe();  //call 1
((B)myA).CleanMe(); //call 2
```

In call 1 and call 2 there will be different behavior (I am not 100% sure if this also comes under polymorphism or not)

```
4.Polymorphism is a method in which different instances of an object display 
 same behavior.
```

***Modified question :
    4'. Polymorphism is a way in which different instances(of different types) of a class display same behavior.***

Explanation : B is derived from A  and A has virtual method called CleanMe() which is overriden in class B.

Now when   you  say

```
A myA = new B();  // instance of B exits as type A
myA.CleanMe();  //call 1
((B)myA).CleanMe(); //call 2
```

In call 1 and call 2 there will be same behavior.

Comment: Your explanation for your modified version of question 2 is slightly incorrect. It remains correct for classes that are derived from a single parent class. What if you have a situation where C is derived from B, and B is derived from A? C is derived from B, A, and Object. And given the question's wording, you have stated that it can be a type of **only** 2 other instances.

Answer (score 7):

Utterly horrible question! (From the interviewer, not you)

> Polymorphism is a method in which...

A method of what? To do what?

> a class can exist in multiple forms.

Was this a philosophy interview?

> different instances of an object

Instances of an object? Oh my...

Tell that interviewer to get his terminology right before asking questions. The only answer I would give him is to either rephrase it correctly or just ask me "What is polymorphism?"

Comment: @Patel Mayur: Unless someone defines "can exist in multiple forms" I cannot answer, because you can understand anything from this sentence.

Comment: ya i know that but which is correct and its should me more than one

Comment: @Patel The whole question is useless - hence we can hardly answer it (if the question was "What is polymorphism" - well that was answered often enough already). Personally if the whole interview was on such a level I'd have declined the job anyhow - who'd want to work in a company where interviewers have no clue themselves?

Answer (score 2):

> Which of these statements are correct regarding polymorphism?

None of them.

> Polymorphism is a method ...

All alternatives say this, and they are therefore all meaningless because polymorphism is not a method.  It is not a method in the Java sense.  It is not a method in the general English sense.  Polymorphism is a descriptive concept, not a method or process.

> Polymorphism is a method in which a class can exist in multiple forms.

This is incorrect because a class cannot exist in multiple forms.  A class exists in one form.  Other classes can be related to a class (e.g. as superclasses or subclasses), but they are *different* classes.

> Polymorphism is a method in which a class can exist in only Two forms.

This is incorrect for the same reason as the previous alternative.

> Polymorphism is a method in which diffrent instances of an object displays diffrent behavior

This is incorrect because an object is an instance (of a class), and cannot *have* instances.  Also, "displays different behaviour" is so vague that it could apply (or not) in cases where there is no polymorphism whatsoever.

> Polymorphism is a method in which diffrent instances of an object displays same behavior

This is incorrect for the same reason as the previous alternative.

---

So there we have it.  None of the stated alternatives are correct.  In fact, none of the alternatives even make any sense from a terminological perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose the first option. take a look here: [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)

> polymorphism in the context of object-oriented programming, is the ability to create a variable, a function, or an object that has more than one form. The word derives from the Greek "πολυμορφισμός" meaning "**having multiple forms**"

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism, etymologically speaking means to have different forms.

There are different kinds of polymorphism in IT.

Overloading a method, providing two+ methods of the same class with the same name but different parameters is a way to provide multiple forms to the methods.

Adhoc polymorphism is used when overriding operators for instance in c++. a single statement like a + b can have different forms depending on wha is s added points, vectors, bananas or ints.

Tradionally, the most emphasized form of polymorphism is the implementation of the Liskov substitution priniciple through inheritance in OOP. You provide a class A and descendants of this class, sbuclasses, override one or more of the methods in A : surclasses will redefine a method defined in A and that would have been inherited, they redefine exactly the same method with the same signature.

This form of polymorphism is widely used to provide an extension point to software app, still giving respect to the open closed principle.

It allows for things like

```
for( Vegetal a : vegetals ) 
   a.grow();
```

An app using this statement would have the ability to grow all vegetals and it would be easy to add a new type of vegetal by adding a subclass of Vegetal and redefining it's grow method.

So none of the answer giveb during your interview was close to something interesting, don't work there ;)